# Formatting and parsing using the same format/regex

Tags: regex, scala, pattern-matching, string-formatting

Say I have a formatting something like this: `val format = "a=%d;b=%d;c=%d;d=%d"`. From this same String I want to get a regex that matches this.

```
 val format = "a=%d;b=%d;c=%d;d=%d"
 val regex = format2regex(format)

 def parse(input: String) = input match {
    case regex(aId, bId, cId, dId) => // input matches Format
    case _ => //
 }

 def format2regex(format: String): Regex = ???
```

What would be the body of the `format2regex` function? If impossible, is it possible to make an equivalent `regex2format` function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Verify if String matches a format String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189393/verify-if-string-matches-a-format-string)

Comment: @tenshi It is not an exact duplicate of this question (although the answers are relevant), and Scala specific answers are welcome.

Comment: yeah, sure. But I think it would not be much different with scala (at least from the conceptual perspective - `Pattern` and `String.format` are part of java API at the end of the day).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**format string to regex**

The function to translate a format to a regex could look like this:

```
import scala.util.matching._

val regex_mapping = Map(
  "%d" -> """((?:\\d+[.])?\\d+)"""
  //"%s" => ...
  //"%i" => ...
)

def format2regex(format: String) : Regex =
  ( regex_mapping.foldLeft(format)({ case (accum,(k,v)) => accum.replaceAll(k,v) }) ).r
```

Example

```
scala> val regex = format2regex(format)
regex: scala.util.matching.Regex = a=((?:\d+[.])?\d+);b=((?:\d+[.])?\d+);c=((?:\d+[.])?\d+);d=((?:\d+[.])?\d+)
```

Doing this has some real drawbacks:

- the **parse** function wouldn't work like you wanted it to because the number of possible *matching groups* for in the Regular exppression can not be known in advance. Thus the number of arguments for the *Extractor* in the Pattern match is also unknown.

**regex to format string**
Creating a format string of an arbitrary regex would be near to impossible or a least quite hard, as there a are many ways to formulate regular expressions that achieve the same goal. If you stick to to regular expression created by **format2regex** you could just inverse the mapping.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping for an easier answer, but it appears that you really need to roll your own complex solution to make this possible.